# Replacing all numeric value to formatted string

Tags: python, regex, string, replace

What I am trying to do is:

Find out all the numeric values in a string.

```
input_string = "高露潔光感白輕悅薄荷牙膏100   79.80"

numbers = re.finditer(r'[-+]?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+(?:[eE][-+]?[0-9]+)?',input_string)

for number in numbers:
    print ("{}    start > {}, end > {}".format(number.group(), number.start(0), number.end(0)))

'''Output'''
>>100    start > 12, end > 15
>>79.80    start > 18, end > 23
```

And then I want to replace all the integer and float value to a certain format:

`INT_(number of digit)` and `FLT(number of decimal places)`

eg. `100 -> INT_3  //  79.80 -> FLT_2`

Thus, the expect output string is like this:

```
"高露潔光感白輕悅薄荷牙膏INT_3   FLT2"
```

But the string replace substring method in Python is kind of weird, which can't  archive what I want to do.

So I am trying to use the substring append substring methods

```
string[:number.start(0)] + "INT_%s"%len(number.group()) +.....
```

which looks stupid and most importantly I still can't make it work.

Can anyone give me some advice on this problem?

Comment: Why `re.finditer` if you need to modify the string? Use `re.sub`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `re.sub` and a callback method inside where you can perform various manipulations on the match:

```
import re
def repl(match):
    chunks = match.group(1).split(".")
    if len(chunks) == 2:
        return "FLT_{}".format(len(chunks[1]))
    else:
        return "INT_{}".format(len(chunks[0]))

input_string = "高露潔光感白輕悅薄荷牙膏100   79.80"
result = re.sub(r'[-+]?([0-9]*\.?[0-9]+)(?:[eE][-+]?[0-9]+)?',repl,input_string)
print(result)
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/lpGcyB)

**Details**:

- The regex now has a capturing group over the number part (`([0-9]*\.?[0-9]+)`), this will be analyzed inside the `repl` method
- Inside the `repl` method, Group 1 contents is split with `.` to see if we have a float/double, and if yes, we return the length of the fractional part, else, the length of the integer number.

Comment: Not sure what behavior you intend to get if the number contains an exponent, but the logic is the same: 1) capture, 2) check inside the `repl`, 3) return only what you need to the result.

Comment: Godlike. I am new to Python (porting Swift / Obj-C code to Python). I didn't know you can pass in a repl in re.sub. It is so powerful. Thanks. I read three Stackoverflow answers in other posts which suggest people to use the append sub string approach. re.sub is the best way. thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

You need to group the parts of your regex possibly like this

```
import re

def repl(m):
    if m.group(1) is None: #int
        return ("INT_%i"%len(m.group(2)))        
    else: #float
        return ("FLT_%i"%(len(m.group(2))))

input_string = "高露潔光感白輕悅薄荷牙膏100   79.80"

numbers = re.sub(r'[-+]?([0-9]*\.)?([0-9]+)([eE][-+]?[0-9]+)?',repl,input_string)        

print(numbers)
```

- group 0 is the whole string that was matched (can be used for putting into `float` or `int`)
- group 1 is any digits before the `.` and the `.` itself if exists else it is `None`
- group 2 is all digits after the `.` if it exists else it it is just all digits
- group 3 is the exponential part if existing else `None`

You can get a python-number from it with

```
def parse(m):
    s=m.group(0)
    if m.group(1) is not None or m.group(3) is not None: # if there is a dot or an exponential part it must be a float
        return float(s)
    else:
        return int(s)
```

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew no special reason for not using `format` - `".24"` is still matched with `groups()` returning `(".","24")`. For getting the full number you would use `group(0)` anyway (`int(m.group(0)) if m.group(1) is None else float(m.group(0))`) so this does not look bad to me

Comment: Yes, I have removed the comment. Note that if you provided the code explanation, it would be really helpful for future readers. Your capturing is rather smart, but is not so obvious to a less regex-savvy user.

Answer (score 1):

You probably are looking for something like the code below (of course there are other ways to do it). This one just starts with what you were doing and show how it can be done.

```
import re
input_string = u"高露潔光感白輕悅薄荷牙膏100   79.80"

numbers = re.finditer(r'[-+]?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+(?:[eE][-+]?[0-9]+)?',input_string)

s = input_string
for m in list(numbers)[::-1]:
    num = m.group(0)
    if '.' in num:
        s = "%sFLT_%s%s" % (s[:m.start(0)],str(len(num)-num.index('.')-1),s[m.end(0):])
    else:
        s = "%sINT_%s%s" % (s[:m.start(0)],str(len(num)), s[m.end(0):])
print(s)
```

This may look a bit complicated because there are really several simple problems to solve.

For instance your initial regex find both ints and floats, but you with to apply totally different replacements afterward. This would be much more straightforward if you were doing only one thing at a time. But as parts of floats may look like an int, doing everything at once may not be such a bad idea, you just have to understand that this will lead to a secondary check to discriminate both cases.

Another more fundamental issue is that really you **can't replace anything** in a python string. Python strings are non modifiable objects, henceforth you have to make a copy. This is fine anyway because the format change may need insertion or removal of characters and an inplace replacement wouldn't be efficient.

The last trouble to take into account is that replacement must be made backward, because if you change the beginning of the string the match position would also change and the next replacement wouldn't be at the right place. If we do it backward, all is fine.

Of course I agree that using `re.sub()` is much simpler.